# Elasticsearch querying ids with a filter boolean or query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that should be getting any row that matches one of these ids. The query returns nothing, but should return two rows. If I remove one id I get one row back. I'm assuming it's doing an AND rather than an OR. How can I change this? (In practice I have many more ids to query)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": 1273359
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": 480421
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`ids` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) instead

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": ["1273359", "480421"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the query you had meant "find documents whose id is 1273359 AND 1273359", which is not possible in practice. With the above query, you have an OR instead of a AND and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate your query ! Use this sugar syntaxe instead :

```
{
  "query": {
    "ids" : {
      "values" : ["0", "1"]
    }
  }
}
```