# QueryDSL _id query within script

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I am using Elasticsearch & Kibana v5.6 and within devTools, I am able to use script within querydsl to query for a doc on a fieldname = value, ie:

```
GET indexA/_search
{
  "query":{ "script":{ "script": """
     def a = doc['field1'].value;
     return a == 'value1';
  """}}
}
```

Above would return all doc that has 'value1' as value within the field called 'field1'. But I am unable to search on _id, official doc says that prior to v6 we should use _uid instead so I have tried that with no luck. I am using script because after I am able to use _uid to get value of _id, essentially I want to do some value comparison similar to below:

```
GET indexA/_search
{
  "query":{ "script":{ "script": """
     def a = doc['field1'].value;
     def b = doc['_uid'].value;
     return a == b;
  """}}
}
```

I think devTools is where i want to execute this instead of other places. Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: what does field1 look like, and what happens when you try to run your query at the moment?

Comment: field1 is actually any field inside the document body, when the first query is ran, it'll return all document that contains 'value1'. for example, within Elasticsearch, if I have 3 documents { "name": "Adam", "field1" : "value1"} , { "name": "Tom", "field1" : "value1"},  and { "name": "RC", "field1" : "value2"} then the above query will return 2 doc, Adam and Tom's doc

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to [Query Id's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-ids-query.html) document or [this one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/mapping-id-field.html) but deploying in the wrong context you need to define id's in the separate head of **`ids`** or put under **`term`** field **`_id`**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there another method that you use to compare a field from body vs _id? if so, do you mind sharing your syntax that works in devtools? ie. if I have 2 docs where first doc (_id= 1a) has {"name": "Muhammad", "field1": "1a"} and 2nd doc(_id= 1b) has{"name": "RC", "field1": "1a"}, do you have another way/script that can be run in devTools which will only return the first doc as _id's value matches the doc's field1's value? Thanks

Comment: for this thing, you need to use bool query with multiple match statements 

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797544/elasticsearch-querying-ids-with-a-filter-boolean-or-query

This is what you seek I suppose.

Comment: don't think those are what I am looking for, I am trying to find a way that will do comparison without knowing what the _id is, it could be anything and not static so I am trying to find a dynamic way to say "give me all documents within an index where their _id matches value from this field(field1)"